# How to assign a NavigateUrl to a HyperLinkField (GridView) depending on content

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have a GridView with some BoundFields and some HyperLinkFields. The HyperLinkField, I want to assign a NavigateUrl to only the cells that have the text "Reject" in it.

Here's my MarkUp:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvS25ATransactions" CellSpacing="-1" GridLines="None" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnPreRender="gvS25ATransactions_PreRender" AllowPaging="true" AllowSorting="true" PageSize="10"  runat="server">
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="SIN" SortExpression="SIN" HeaderText="<%$ Resources:S25ATransactions, litSIN %>" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="TRANSACTION_TYPE_DESC_EN" SortExpression="TRANSACTION_TYPE_DESC_EN" HeaderText="<%$ Resources:S25ATransactions, litType %>" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="TRANSACTION_TYPE_DESC_FR" SortExpression="TRANSACTION_TYPE_DESC_FR" HeaderText="<%$ Resources:S25ATransactions, litType %>" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="DATE_UPDATED" SortExpression="DATE_UPDATED" HeaderText="<%$ Resources:S25ATransactions, litDate %>" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="USER_CODE" SortExpression="USER_CODE" HeaderText="<%$ Resources:S25ATransactions, litUser %>" />
    <asp:HyperLinkField DataTextField="STATUS_DESC_EN" SortExpression="STATUS_DESC_EN" HeaderText="<%$ Resources:S25ATransactions, litStatus %>" />
    <asp:HyperLinkField DataTextField="STATUS_DESC_FR" SortExpression="STATUS_DESC_FR" HeaderText="<%$ Resources:S25ATransactions, litStatus %>" />
</Columns>
<PagerStyle CssClass="pagination" />
```

And this is what I have tried to do so far:

```
Protected Sub gvS25ATransactions_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles gvS25ATransactions.RowDataBound

    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then

        For Each column As DataControlField In gvS25ATransactions.Columns

            If column.HeaderText = "Status" Or column.HeaderText = "Statut" Then

                For i As Integer = 0 To gvS25ATransactions.Rows.Count - 1

                    If gvS25ATransactions.Rows(i).Cells(5).Text = "Rejected by SD110" Then
                        Dim hl As HyperLink = TryCast(e.Row.FindControl("HyperLink1"), HyperLink)
                        hl.NavigateUrl = "#coucou"
                    End If

                Next

            End If

        Next

    End If

End Sub
```

The cells with the text "Reject" will be in either the column 5 or 6 (one is English, the other is French).

When I do the code above, it never goes in this for loop.

```
For i As Integer = 0 To gvS25ATransactions.Rows.Count - 1
```

It says the "i" is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to it's protection level

Help?

**UPDATE**

Here's the new markup I have put in regards to RedDevil79's suggestions

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvS25ATransactions" CellSpacing="-1" GridLines="None" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnPreRender="gvS25ATransactions_PreRender" AllowPaging="true" AllowSorting="true" PageSize="10"  runat="server">
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="SIN" SortExpression="SIN" HeaderText="<%$ Resources:S25ATransactions, litSIN %>" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="TRANSACTION_TYPE_DESC_EN" SortExpression="TRANSACTION_TYPE_DESC_EN" HeaderText="<%$ Resources:S25ATransactions, litType %>" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="TRANSACTION_TYPE_DESC_FR" SortExpression="TRANSACTION_TYPE_DESC_FR" HeaderText="<%$ Resources:S25ATransactions, litType %>" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="DATE_UPDATED" SortExpression="DATE_UPDATED" HeaderText="<%$ Resources:S25ATransactions, litDate %>" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="USER_CODE" SortExpression="USER_CODE" HeaderText="<%$ Resources:S25ATransactions, litUser %>" />
    <asp:TemplateField  SortExpression="STATUS_DESC_EN" HeaderText="<%$ Resources:S25ATransactions, litStatus %>">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:HyperLink ID="STATUS_DESC_EN" runat="server"><%# Eval("STATUS_DESC_EN")%></asp:HyperLink>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField  SortExpression="STATUS_DESC_FR" HeaderText="<%$ Resources:S25ATransactions, litStatus %>">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:HyperLink ID="STATUS_DESC_FR" runat="server"><%# Eval("STATUS_DESC_FR")%></asp:HyperLink>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>       
</Columns>
<PagerStyle CssClass="pagination" />
```

And this is the VB code

```
Protected Sub gvS25ATransactions_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles gvS25ATransactions.RowDataBound

    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        Dim hl As HyperLink = TryCast(e.Row.FindControl("STATUS_DESC_EN"), HyperLink)
        Dim hl2 As HyperLink = TryCast(e.Row.FindControl("STATUS_DESC_FR"), HyperLink)
        If hl.Text = "Rejected by SD110" Or hl2.Text = "Rejeté par SD110" Then
            hl.NavigateUrl = "#coucou"
            hl2.NavigateUrl = "#coucoufr"
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

The problem I am facing now is that hl.Text and hl2.Text are always ="" so it never goes in the if statement

Comment: All the text in the gridview comes from the database. The text "Reject" would be in the STATUS_DESC_EN or STATUS_DESC_FR ("Rejet" in this case) columns.

Comment: are you sure the error is referring to this `i` in the code ? I don't see any problem with it

Comment: well... there's no error with the i ... it's just that it never goes in the loop because it says that "'i' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to it's protection level"

Comment: `Rejected by SD110` is this line the same for all the cells? as in, would other cell for example be `Rejected by SD222`

Comment: instead of accessing the cells, you can cast the data-item and check against the field values; I can show you c# codes if you want; first, check if it is a datarow: `e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow` then cast: `var dataItem = e.Row.DataItem as <your_data_item_type>`

Comment: No the content of the Status column is either: Accepted, Pending, Rejected by OLIS (LO11), Rejected by SD110, Disregarded or Accepted with warnings. I want the cells that have "Rejected by SD110" to have a NavigateUrl, the rest, nothing.

Comment: Are you trying to cast a HyperLinkField control into a HyperLink control? I think they are different.

Comment: No... I just want to assign the NavigateUrl to my HyperLinkField depending on the content as stated above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Convert the 2 hyperlink fields in GridView to template and change the RowDataBound to:

```
If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then

    For Each column As DataControlField In gvS25ATransactions.Columns

        If column.HeaderText = "Status" Or column.HeaderText = "Statut" Then               

                If e.Row.Cells(5).Text = "Rejected by SD110" Then
                    Dim hl As HyperLink = TryCast(e.Row.FindControl("HyperLink1"), HyperLink)
                    hl.NavigateUrl = "#coucou"
                End If

        End If

    Next

End If
```

Explanation:

You have to convert the hyperlink fields to template because you need the name of the control in FindControl function.

In RowDataBound you don't need to iterate through all the rows of gridview. The RowDataBound is executed for every row in gridview when data is added to it.
That's why you don't need the for loop.

**Update:**

```
If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
     Dim hl As HyperLink = TryCast(e.Row.FindControl("STATUS_DESC_EN"), HyperLink)
     Dim hl2 As HyperLink = TryCast(e.Row.FindControl("STATUS_DESC_FR"), HyperLink)
     If hl.Text = "Rejected by SD110" Or hl2.Text = "Rejected by SD110" Then
         hl.NavigateUrl = "#coucou"
     End If
End If
```

Your Hyperlink tags are not well formed:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvS25ATransactions" CellSpacing="-1" GridLines="None" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnPreRender="gvS25ATransactions_PreRender" AllowPaging="true" AllowSorting="true" PageSize="10"  runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="SIN" SortExpression="SIN" HeaderText="<%$ Resources:S25ATransactions, litSIN %>" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="TRANSACTION_TYPE_DESC_EN" SortExpression="TRANSACTION_TYPE_DESC_EN" HeaderText="<%$ Resources:S25ATransactions, litType %>" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="TRANSACTION_TYPE_DESC_FR" SortExpression="TRANSACTION_TYPE_DESC_FR" HeaderText="<%$ Resources:S25ATransactions, litType %>" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="DATE_UPDATED" SortExpression="DATE_UPDATED" HeaderText="<%$ Resources:S25ATransactions, litDate %>" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="USER_CODE" SortExpression="USER_CODE" HeaderText="<%$ Resources:S25ATransactions, litUser %>" />
        <asp:TemplateField  SortExpression="STATUS_DESC_EN" HeaderText="<%$ Resources:S25ATransactions, litStatus %>">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HyperLink ID="STATUS_DESC_EN" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("STATUS_DESC_EN")%>'></asp:HyperLink>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField  SortExpression="STATUS_DESC_FR" HeaderText="<%$ Resources:S25ATransactions, litStatus %>">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HyperLink ID="STATUS_DESC_FR" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("STATUS_DESC_FR")%>'></asp:HyperLink>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>       
    </Columns>
    <PagerStyle CssClass="pagination" />
</asp:GridView>
```

You have to Bind the field to the text property of Hyperlink.

**Important:** the Text property only works with ' not "

Comment: Thanks for the help! So... I changed my <asp:hyperlinkfield> to this <asp:TemplateField  SortExpression="STATUS_DESC_EN" HeaderText="<%$ Resources:S25ATransactions, litStatus %>">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HyperLink ID="STATUS_DESC_EN" runat="server"><%# Eval("STATUS_DESC_EN")%></asp:HyperLink>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>. And when I step trough the code, e.Row.Cells(5).Text, is always =""

Comment: That didn't work either. hl and hl2 are always ="" I've updated my original post with the new markup... is it OK?

Comment: It's ok, just change hl and hl2 findcontrol ID, see my update.

Comment: Well yes, obviously, I changed that when I put it in my code lol ... I'll update the original post with the code